# use concatenated variable from mysql for php query

Tags: php, mysql, variables

running the below query through a php webpage returns 0 results.

```
$category = $_POST['cat'];
$var = "_one";

$category = $category . $var;

$array = $pdo->prepare("select * from my_table where id = :id and category_name = :category LIMIT :start, :limit");
$array->execute(array(':id' => $id, ':category' => $category, ':start' => $start, ':limit' => $limit));
```

running the below query through mysql phpmyadmin returns 5 results.

```
select * from my_table where id = 1 and category_name = 'test_one';
```

Why is the first query returning 0 results when I know there are 5 results?

Comment: You need to understand how preparing statements work. By preparing, you're binding each input element to a certain type. Try binding the category_name in your first example, like so:

$array = $pdo->prepare("select * from my_table where id = :id and category_name = :category_name LIMIT :start, :limit");

Comment: Lose the `mysql_real_escape_string`!!  That is completely useless here.

Comment: Then you need to verify what your $category contains, if your query works without the category_name. Do a var_dump($category) after $category = mysql_real_escape_string($category); (MySQL Real Escape String is unneccessary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For debugging purposes please try ( and check the code comments....)

```
<?php

// let's make it more unlikely you miss an error condition/message
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


$category = $_POST['cat'];
$var = "_one";
$category = $category . $var;

// never mix mysql_* functions with pdo
// $category = wrong_mysql_real_escape_string_wrong($category);


// make category a named parameter of the statement like all the other parameters
// doesn't make sense to "intermix" this one....
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        my_table
    WHERE
        id = :id 
        AND category_name = :category 
    LIMIT
        :start, :limit
');

// you're sure all the variables exist at this point and contain what you expect?
$params = array(
    'id'=>$id,
    'category'=>$category,
    'start'=>$start,
    'limit' => $limit
);
// let's make sure by printing them ...
echo '<pre>executing statement with: ', htmlspecialchars(var_export($params, true)), "</pre>\r\n";
$stmt->execute( $params );
```

Comment: oops, forgot to pass $params to execute -> `$stmt->execute( $params );`